# Extend/Fill Time Series Data with zeros and constant values in Pandas with Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i have a problem with extending my time series data. I have following dataframe:

```
date_first = df1['date'].min()  # is 2016-08-08
date_last = df1['date'].max()  # is 2016-08-20

>>> df1
         date         customer     qty
149481   2016-08-08   A            400
161933   2016-08-10   A            200
167172   2016-08-13   B            900
170296   2016-08-15   A            300
178221   2016-08-20   B            150
```

Now i am reindexing the frame and get following frame:

```
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)

>>> df1
             customer     qty
date
2016-08-08   A            400
2016-08-10   A            200
2016-08-13   B            900
2016-08-15   A            300
2016-08-20   B            150
```

Now i am trying to extend my time series data for every single customer by the earliest date and latest date like following:

```
ix = pd.DataFrame({on_column: pd.Series([date_first, date_last]), 'qty': 0})
result = df1.reindex(ix)
```

This does not give me my expected result, which i want to look like following frame:

```
    >>> df1
    date         customer     qty
0   2016-08-08   A            400
1   2016-08-08   B            0
2   2016-08-09   A            0
3   2016-08-09   B            0
4   2016-08-10   A            200
5   2016-08-10   B            0
...
24  2016-08-20   A            0
25  2016-08-20   B            150
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by original `MultiIndex` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by both columns:

```
date_first = df1['date'].min()  
date_last = df1['date'].max() 

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(date_first, date_last, freq='d'), 
                                  df1['customer'].unique()], names=['date','customer'])
print (mux)
result = df1.set_index(['date', 'customer']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (result)
         date customer  qty
0  2016-08-08        A  400
1  2016-08-08        B    0
2  2016-08-09        A    0
3  2016-08-09        B    0
4  2016-08-10        A  200
5  2016-08-10        B    0
6  2016-08-11        A    0
7  2016-08-11        B    0
8  2016-08-12        A    0
9  2016-08-12        B    0
10 2016-08-13        A    0
11 2016-08-13        B  900
12 2016-08-14        A    0
13 2016-08-14        B    0
14 2016-08-15        A  300
15 2016-08-15        B    0
16 2016-08-16        A    0
17 2016-08-16        B    0
18 2016-08-17        A    0
19 2016-08-17        B    0
20 2016-08-18        A    0
21 2016-08-18        B    0
22 2016-08-19        A    0
23 2016-08-19        B    0
24 2016-08-20        A    0
25 2016-08-20        B  150
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you very much. I only had to reindex my raw dataframe by following code snippet  df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution wrapped into a function:

```
@staticmethod
def extend_time_series_data(data, date_column, customer_column, qty_column):
    data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
    date_first = data[date_column].min()
    date_last = data[date_column].max()
    data[date_column] = pd.to_datetime(data[date_column])
    data[qty_column] = pd.to_numeric(data[qty_column])

    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(date_first, date_last, freq='d'),
                                      data[customer_column].unique()], names=[date_column, customer_column])
    # print(mux)
    result = data.set_index([date_column, customer_column]).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
    # print(result)
    print('Extending time series data was successful!')
    return result
```

Maybe it will help someone out of a similar problem.