# Is there a way to do a pandas unstack fillna (expand to cartesian) without calling unstack directly?

Tags: pandas

So if you have a Series with two index levels named ['a', 'b'] you might call

```py
s.unstack(level='a').fillna(0).stack()
```

To turn the series into "square" format. i.e. arity(a) * arity(b).

Is there a direct way to do this with a resample instead of stack unstack?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Or you need `reindex` with `pd.date_range` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53277461/2901002) ?